# Is my question suitable on project management or some other forum?

Tags: discussion, support, specific-question

It's been asked before about the importance of knowing mathematics for programmers and I wonder if you think that mathematics will be more or less important for software development in the future. More specifically do you expect a software developer or a programmer in the future to know more or less mathematics? I would believe that most good programmers know some calculus, algebra and/or discrete mathematics or combinatorics to be able to analyse a problem.

Is this question something that would not get closed and might get an answer? I don't know if it's good for math, pm or programmers.

### Question

> Will mathematics be more or less important for the software developers
>   in the for future e.g. 50 yearsw from now, 100 years from now or even further on? I chose to study
>   computer science when I thought that it was important to know more
>   mathematics. I assumed that you had to know much mathematics to be a
>   skilled programmer. Then I read here and there that you might not know
>   much mathematics at all to be a programmer.
>
> Or would you think that roles in teamwork will get more separated and
>   specialized between programmers, architects/designers and and software
>   analysts where programmers might not have to know much mathematics
>   becuse an analyst already analyzed and did the mathematics for a
>   specific program, where the architect/designer was responsible for
>   design and a programmer just translates a problem that was already
>   guaranteed to work and the programmer must not now mathematics and
>   that could be the responsibility of a software analyst?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like a math specific question and therefore relevant to the math site. Doesn't seem like a fit here since most of the most widely known pm approaches do not use heavy math nor have math as a prerequisite. There are, of course, areas such as risk management, running monte carlo simulations and other areas where math is used. But I don't think that's sufficient to make pmse a good home for a math question.

Answer (score 0):

Just ask it on https://math.stackexchange.com/